# Digital Clock in visual C# windows form not updating automatically

Tags: c#, windows, forms, clock

I am new to visual C# windows form. I am making digital clock so that when I press a button, time will start and will keep on updating i.e. means seconds should keep on going and when i press stop button, it should stop. But in my current code, time is getting displayed but its seconds are not updating. Can anyone help me. Thanks.

CODE

```
namespace DTDemo
{
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private DateTime datetime;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // start button
    {
        datetime = DateTime.Now;
        String time = datetime.Hour + ":" + datetime.Minute + ":" + datetime.Second;
        label1.Text = time; 
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //stop button
    {
        label1.Text = " ";
    }
}
}
```

I have tried putting it in while(true) but then it freezes nothing happens. Please help thanks.!

Comment: Add a *timer* and ot its `Tick` event update the label

Comment: You'll want to use a [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for that. Hint: it has got `Start()` and `Stop()` methods and a `Tick` event.

Comment: Use the `Timer` class from the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace.

Comment: Your clock will only show the time when you click the button right now.  Put a timer in your program, set it to fire every second, and have the timer event update your clock.

Comment: timer...looks interesting. let me get more info about it. BTW can you give an example?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Of course not, you need a timer to keep updating the label.
Try the following:

```
namespace DTDemo
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      private DateTime datetime;
      System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);

      public Form1()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
          timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
      }

      void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
      {
        MethodInvoker method = new MethodInvoker(delegate{
        datetime = DateTime.Now;
        String time = datetime.Hour + ":" + datetime.Minute + ":" + datetime.Second;
        label1.Text = time; 
        });
        if (label1.InvokeRequired)
            label1.Invoke(method);
        else
            method();
    }

      private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) // start button
      {
          timer.Start();
      }

      private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //stop button
      {
          timer.Stop();
          label1.Text = " ";
      }
    }
  }
```

BTW, I'm using the 'System.Timers.Timer' and not the 'System.Windows.Forms.Timer' since the WinForms timer will freeze if the UI freezes (since it runs on the main UI thread). The System.Timers.Timer, on the other hand, runs on a worker thread and only posts the UI requests to the main context